# I need help working out someone's first name and last name

Tags: узус, выбор-имени

I need to work out the first and last name of a Russian man,`SEIDOV CHARY`.

Which is first and which is last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SEIDOV** looks like a surname due to the ending `-ov`.

**CHARY**  must then be his first name.

However neither of them sound ethnically Russian. It could belong to an Azeri or to someone from one of the Central Asian states.

Comment: then why just not ask the recipient directly than make guesswork ? The person definitely knows his names :-D

Answer (score 5):

I googled it. There's a man with the name Чары Сеидов from Tatarstan. Chary is definitely his first name and Seidov's his surname.